# The assembly is not strongly named or is not signed with the minimal key length while running .msi file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, gac

I am registering dll in GAC. My dll is not strongly named.I have error like 'The assembly is not strongly named or is not signed with the minimal key length'. Is it compulsorily that the dll should be strongly typed? Or if any other option please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Assemblies must be strong name signed (not strongly typed) with sn.exe before they can be installed in the GAC. sn.exe will generate a key file. In VS 2013 in the Properies of the Dll build there is a Signing option, just check the Sign the assembly box and browse to the file created by sn.exe (or in some cases use a standard snk file that your company uses for its assemblies).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. It worked fine to register dll in GAC. I am using WIX to copy files in a folder which is in Program files. If I copy files at other location it works fine but in Program files I am unable to copy files. What could be the issue. Please help..

Comment: This sounds like you need to run the installer or cmd.exe as administrator to have write access to that program files directory.